# Can a catatonic creature (0 charisma) be controlled via domination magic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, mind-control

If a creature’s ability score is reduced to 0, say charisma, and the creature becomes helpless (in this case catatonic), does domination (mind affecting) magic even function?

My intuition would be that while the spell might succeed, the affected subject won’t be able to respond to the caster’s commands until the ability score is raised.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It can be targeted, but not controlled.

The rules state that a creature with 0 Charisma is unconscious.  [From the SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#abilityDamaged):

> A character with Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma 0 is unconscious.

Unconsciousness provides no special immunity to mind-affecting spells, since the only targeting requirement of mind-affecting spells is that the target has an Intelligence of at least 1.  [From the SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#descriptor):

> A mind-affecting spell works only against creatures with an Intelligence score of 1 or higher.

Domination effects do not specifically remove unconsciousness, however, so the dominated character cannot do anything.

As a corollary, a creature knocked down to 0 Intelligence cannot be dominated, unlike one knocked down to 0 Wisdom or Charisma.

Comment: My group is using the dungeon master Manuel 3.5 rules located on page 291, and states this with respect to charisma: “Charisma 0 means that the character is withdrawn into a catatonic, coma like stupor, helpless.” Additionally, there are some effects that turn creatures into followers when drained to 0, such as the Gray Jester: “they undertake no actions unless the gray jester that drained them gives them orders”… [they] become followers and soldiers of the gray jester”. In the scenarios where 0 ability score creatures are not unconscious, can dominant magic effect them?

Comment: @FrankCastle The Gray Jester's ability to control creatures by reducing their charisma to zero is a very special case. Whether it is possible to dominate someone who has been turned into such a follower might be worth a separate question.